# c# Datagridview перенести значение выбранной строки в Listview

Tags: c#

нужно перенести выбранную строку datagridview в listview, после перенесенные данные необходимо добавить в базу данных. какие действия необходимо выполнит для этого ? datagridview заполнятся из базы данных mysql.

```
 public partial class Country : Form
{
    public struct city
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public string country;

        public city(int _id, string _name, string _country)
        {
            id = _id;
            name = _name;
            country = _country;
        }
    }
    
    public Country()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Country_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = Condatabase.GetDBConnection())
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT city.id, city.name, country.name AS country FROM city LEFT JOIN country ON city.countryID = country.id", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
       
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        listView1.Columns.Add("id", 40, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        listView1.Columns.Add("name", 90, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        listView1.View = View.Details;
    }
    

    private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(dataGridView1.SelectedRows, DragDropEffects.Move);

    }

    private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection rows = (DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection));
    //    DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows = (DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection));
    
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
         {
            listView1.Items.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
         
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
         } 
      
    }

    private void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection)))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }
     
    
}
```

Comment: Для чего вы создали структуру `city`, но не используете её? / Для чего вы использовали `DataTable`  и привязку данных, но потом работаете напрямую со строками `dataGridView1`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov,  честно сказать еще полностью  не знаком с привязкой данных, только начал,  Datatable-ом отображал данные в datagridview

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov.  не могли бы объяснить порядок действий для ADO.net?

Comment: Думаю стоит использовать паттерн MVVM, там все из коробки будет работать при правильной настройке привязок. Ну или MVP если это winforms

Comment: @Lenz для winforms подробного применения MVVM в просторах интернета не нашел

Comment: я же написал что если это winforms то MVP (Model-View-Preserntation)

Comment: @Lenz, понял, пойду изучать mvp, насчет моего вопроса можете написать порядок действий ?

Comment: после привязки через MVP у вас будет поле 
public ТипСтрокиДатагридвью SelectedItem {get; set;}
- это и есть выбранная вами строка
её можно будет закинуть куда угодно, можно ловить выбор новой строки в set
ну а запись в БД сделать по кнопке отдельно, благо что после привязки у вас не будет проблем с тем чтобы обратиться к данным, которые нужно записать